# Как указать путь к файлу при создании файлового потока в Node.js 16.x?

Tags: node.js

В [этом божественном, но устаревшем скринкасте по NodeJS](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs#nodejs-streams-net) был показан такой способ создания файлового потока (переписал на TypeScript):

```
import FileSystem from "fs";

const fileReadingStream: FileSystem.ReadStream = new FileSystem.ReadStream(FILE_PATH);
```

TypeScript скажет, что нынче такой способ не валиден:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableOptions | undefined'
```

Посмотрев определения типов я так и не понял, как предлагается теперь создать файловый поток.

Класс `ReadStream` своего собственного (не унаследованного) конструктора не имеет, а унаследованный от `stream.Readable` конструктор имеет вид

```
constructor(opts?: ReadableOptions);
```

где `ReadableOptions` - интерфейс вида

```
interface ReadableOptions extends StreamOptions<Readable> {
  encoding?: BufferEncoding | undefined;
  read?(this: Readable, size: number): void;
}
```

Куда же подевалась опция для указания пути?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен [fs.cerateReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options)

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

Параметры:

```
path <string> | <Buffer> | <URL>
options <string> | <Object>
```

Возвращает

```
<fs.ReadStream>
```

Пример кода

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';

// Create a stream from some character device.
const stream = createReadStream('/dev/input/event0');
setTimeout(() => {
  stream.close(); // This may not close the stream.
  // Artificially marking end-of-stream, as if the underlying resource had
  // indicated end-of-file by itself, allows the stream to close.
  // This does not cancel pending read operations, and if there is such an
  // operation, the process may still not be able to exit successfully
  // until it finishes.
  stream.push(null);
  stream.read(0);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!